# Laravel real repository pattern

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I am implementing a repository pattern in Laravel and have a question about the implementation.

For example, I can make `UserRepository` class have methods which follow `Eloquent` standard:

```
public function create(array $properties)
{
    return $this->entity->create($properties);
}

public function update($id, array $properties)
{
    return $this->find($id)->update($properties);
}

public function delete($id)
{
    return $this->find($id)->delete();
}
```

And then inject that repository where ever I need to do something with my user.

The problem I see here is...what happens in the back when I do for example:

```
$this->userRepository->authenticatedUser()->posts
```

Does this violate having the repository pattern if the `posts` relation is called through `Eloquent` then?

Does having a "real" repository pattern mean then to handle all possible relations which are loaded through the `User` model?

Comment: You're no longer using the repository, so it's related to what you specify as the return value for authenticatedUser in your interface.

Comment: In my opinion, any attempt to use a 'true' repository pattern with an active record implementation like Eloquent would require a lot of duplication of the eloquent model itself. You can already see that from your code.
I don't think it's worth the effort really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it DRY. Here you would just duplicate a lot of code that Eloquent already provides.

However you could use the RepositoryPattern if the calls are more complicated and you don't want to repeat the logic all over your codebase.

I.e.

```
public function clientContact($clientId) {
     return \Auth::user()->manager()->superBoss()->company()->clients()->where('client_id', $clientID)->primaryContact()->firstOrFail();
}
```

In that case it makes sense.

But if you want the authenticated user's posts then just work with eloquent relationships.

```
$posts = \Auth::user()->posts()->get();
```

Comment: In my own opinion, there is very little chance that I will some day come and say "hey, let's switch Eloquent with another ORM"! That being said, I would ignore the repository pattern completely in Laravel. However, I am being asked by the company to do the implementations, so I have to see what are best approaches for it

Comment: @Norgul Hmm, in that case you probably would need to create and adapter which handles everything, maybe forward the relationship, i.e. create something like https://github.com/bosnadev/repository. So if something changes you would only need to modify the adapter. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter/php